# Create a new MySql column from result of others with PHP or MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this situation:

```
    NAME    |    SURNAME    |    RANK
  JASMINE     VISMITANANDA        4
  JASMINE     VISMITANANDA        6
```

And I would love to obtain this situation using MySql and / or PHP

```
NAME    |    SURNAME    |    RANK
JASMINE     VISMITANANDA      4 - 6
```

There's a way to do it without looping too much with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `group by`.  This might do what you want:

```
select name, surname, concat_ws(' - ', min(rank), max(rank)) as rank
from table t
group by name, surname;
```